# Find all expressions of four 10s

Tags: c++, prolog

I was challenged with a CS problem.

The problem consists of recursively finding which expressions of the form ((10+10)/(10+10)) produces a number. For example, ((10+10)/(10+10)) produces 1. Find all the other expressions using the operators +, -, *, /, with 4 numbers of 10, and all the combinations of parentheses to enforce orders of operations.

I was referred to the Reverse Polish Notation, but that relies on postfix notation, which isn’t required to solve this problem.

Some pseudocode I have is this. I know using recursion is the easiest way to solve this problem. But don't know how to make sure I get all combinations.

```
build([10,10,10,10], Expression) :-
      Operator
     /       \
   [10]     [10,10,10]
             Operator
              /     \
           [10]     [10,10]
                    Operator
                     /    \
                   [10]   [10]
```

This is a problem I am trying to solve in Prolog but C++ is good as well.

Comment: You'll find folks are more likely to help you if you've actually tried to solve the problem yourself and encountered some particular problems with your solution, rather than expecting others to solve your problem for you.

Comment: Under your `[10,10,10,10]` you could have `10 op [10, 10, 10]` or `[10, 10] op [10, 10]` or `[10, 10, 10] op 10`. You only show the first case.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a partial solution which I will outline here and hopefully it will get you moving and you can find the complete solution.

The first tool you need is the ability to make some expressions:

```
build_expr(X, Y, X+Y).
build_expr(X, Y, X*Y).
build_expr(X, Y, X-Y).
build_expr(X, Y, X/Y).
```

This defines `build_expr/3`, which takes two variables or expressions and produces a new expression. This is how we are going to permute the operators. Now we need a way to handle the lists, so let's define `build_expr/2` that operates on a list at once:

```
% base case: we are down to two variables and call build_expr/3
build_expr([X,Y], Expr) :- build_expr(X, Y, Expr).

% inductive case: make the expression on the rest of the list and combine
% with the leading variable here
build_expr([X|Rest], Expr) :-
    build_expr(Rest, Expr0),
    build_expr(X, Expr0, Expr).
```

Let's get a few solutions so we get the flavor of what it's doing:

```
3 ?- build_expr([10,10,10,10],X).
X = 10+(10+(10+10)) ;
X = 10*(10+(10+10)) ;
X = 10-(10+(10+10)) ;
X = 10/(10+(10+10)) ;
X = 10+10*(10+10) ;
X = 10*(10*(10+10)) ;
X = 10-10*(10+10) ;
X = 10/(10*(10+10)) ;
X = 10+(10-(10+10)) ;
X = 10*(10-(10+10)) ;
X = 10-(10-(10+10)) ;
X = 10/(10-(10+10)) ;
```

This looks pretty good to me. But like I said, I'm only generating the right-leaning tree. You will have to modify or replace `build_expr/2` to produce the other shapes, if they actually matter (which I'm not convinced they do).

Now let's make the next step simpler by bundling in evaluation:

```
build_eval(L, Value) :- build_expr(L, Expr), Value is Expr.
```

Now we should be able to find all the unique solutions using `setof/3`:

```
6 ?- setof(X, build_eval([10,10,10,10],X), Results).
ERROR: Arithmetic: evaluation error: `zero_divisor'
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [15] _582 is 10/(10* ...)
ERROR:   [14] build_eval([10,10|...],_622) at /Users/dlyons/fourtens.pl:11
ERROR:   [13] '$bags':findall_loop(_664,user:build_eval(...,_682),_668,[]) at /usr/local/Cellar/swi-prolog/7.6.4/libexec/lib/swipl-7.6.4/boot/bags.pl:97
ERROR:   [12] setup_call_catcher_cleanup('$bags':'$new_findall_bag','$bags':findall_loop(_728,...,_732,[]),_710,'$bags':'$destroy_findall_bag') at /usr/local/Cellar/swi-prolog/7.6.4/libexec/lib/swipl-7.6.4/boot/init.pl:443
ERROR:    [8] '$bags':setof(_770,user:build_eval(...,_786),_774) at /usr/local/Cellar/swi-prolog/7.6.4/libexec/lib/swipl-7.6.4/boot/bags.pl:240
ERROR:    [7] <user>
ERROR:
ERROR: Note: some frames are missing due to last-call optimization.
ERROR: Re-run your program in debug mode (:- debug.) to get more detail.
ERROR:   [13] '$bags':findall_loop(_664,user:build_eval(...,_682),_668,[]) aabort
% Execution Aborted
```

Oops. Division by zero error. No problem, let's catch that and fail in those cases instead:

```
9 ?- setof(X, catch(build_eval([10,10,10,10],X), E, fail), Results), writeln(Results).
[-990,-900,-190,-100,-80,-20,-1,-0.1111111111111111,
 0,0.01,0.05,0.09090909090909091,0.3333333333333333,1.0,1,
 5.0,9.5,9.9,10,10.1,10.5,20.0,20,40,100.0,100,
 120,210,300,1010,1100,2000,10000]
```

I fiddled with the formatting there a little, but I think that's a pretty good solution, but I can already see one missing solution: (10+10)*(10+10)=400. So you will have to get more creative with `build_expr/2` to make it produce other shapes of tree.

#### Edit: Adding the rest of the solutions

I found [an answer by @gusbro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12425919/812818) that gives a way to enumerate the trees. I wasn't able to get it to work with the recursive trickery I was doing there (maybe someone else will show me a very easy trick) but I was able to adapt his answer to your problem, to wit:

```
build_tree([I1,I2|Items], Expr) :-
    append([L0|LR], [R0|RR], [I1,I2|Items]),
    build_tree([L0|LR], Left),
    build_tree([R0|RR], Right),
    build_expr(Left, Right, Expr).
build_tree([E], E).
```

Why am I using `[L0|LR]` and `[R0|RR]` instead of `LeftList` and `RightList` or some such? This is how I'm turning @gusbro's numeric constraints into list length constraints and ensuring that I always have at least one element in both the left and right lists, so my recursive calls to `build_tree/2` will succeed.

Simplifying `build_expr/3` from above down to a single operator you can see this generates all the various flavors you'd expect:

```
?- build_tree([10,10,10,10],X).
X = 10+(10+(10+10)) ;
X = 10+(10+10+10) ;
X = 10+10+(10+10) ;
X = 10+(10+10)+10 ;
X = 10+10+10+10 ;
false.
```

Switch it back, because we're still using the `build_expr/3` function from the earlier example. I have simplified the evaluation somewhat using this `build_eval/2` predicate:

```
build_eval(L, Value) :- 
    build_tree(L, Expr), catch(Value is Expr, _, fail).
```

Here's what the final solution looks like:

```
 ?- setof(X, build_eval([10,10,10,10], X), Res), writeln(Res).
[-990,-900,-190,-100,-99,-90,-80,-20,-19,-10,-9.9,-9.5,-9,
 -8,-1.1111111111111112,-1,-0.9,-0.1111111111111111,
 0,0.01,0.05,0.09090909090909091,0.1111111111111111,
 0.2,0.3333333333333333,0.9,0.9090909090909091,1.0,1,
 1.1,1.1111111111111112,2,3,5.0,5,8,9,9.5,9.9,10,10.1,10.5,11,
 12,19,20.0,20,21,40,80,90,99,100.0,100,101,110,120,190,
 200,210,300,400,900,990,1010,1100,2000,10000]
```

Wow, quite a few alternatives, 68 to be exact!

Comment: Yeah I do need all of the other variations of the tree. The only thin I can't figure out is how to split the array differently to get different results. Like the way the Head and tail are it allows you to create only that type of tree.

Comment: @Programmer try `build_expr(Expr0, X, Expr)` and then see if you can peel off more of the list (Prolog does not have arrays) and build the tree other ways, such as `build_expr([X,Y|Rest], Expr) :- build_expr(X,Y, Expr0), build_expr(Rest, Expr1), build_expr(Expr0, Expr1, Expr)` and see if you can make progress.

Comment: @Programmer I have edited the answer with some more information, take a look!