# Find all expressions of four 10s In Haskell

Tags: haskell

was challenged with a CS problem.

The problem consists of recursively finding which expressions of the form ((10+10)/(10+10)) produces a number. For example, ((10+10)/(10+10)) produces 1. Find all the other expressions using the operators +, -, *, /, with 4 numbers of 10, and all the combinations of parentheses to enforce orders of operations.

I was referred to the Reverse Polish Notation, but that relies on postfix notation, which isn’t required to solve this problem.

Some pseudocode I have is this. I know using recursion is the easiest way to solve this problem. But don't know how to make sure I get all combinations.

```
build([10,10,10,10], Expression) :-
        Operator
       /       \
    [10]     [10,10,10]
              Operator
               /     \
            [10]     [10,10]
                     Operator
                      /    \
                    [10]   [10]
```

This is a problem I am trying to solve in Haskell.

Comment: You already asked the same problem in Prolog, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52798641/find-all-expressions-of-four-10s please show some *effort* yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse Polish Notation is a viable method to solve this problem. You can insert arithmetic (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`) operators somewhere between two 10s in the following quasi-RPN:

`10 10 10 10`

After generating a possible RPN, convert it to infix notation. For example, `10 10 + 10 10 + /` is converted to `(10+10)/(10+10)`.

However, not all permutations are legal. For example, the following RPN is illegal:

`10 + 10 - 10 * 10 /`

You must ensure that every operator have enough operands. In the above example, the first `+` only has one 10 as its operand, so it's illegal.

You can simply hard-code all legal operator placing rules into the code.